Political Relations on an Interstellar Scale
I'm working on a sci-fantasy (think wizards calling in JDAM strikes) setting where humanity has  colonized about a hundred tightly located solar systems split up between 5-6 giant ethno-political factions, called constates, and many smaller ones. I want these factions to have political interactions like countries on Earth, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how that would work. My setting has scalable FTL travel and terraforming tech which allows worlds to be habitable in about a century. Communication is just about instant, and every planet within a solar system can be visited in a month's time, or else a ship can cut straight through in about a week, followed by under a day of travel between solar systems. Each faction:

Is made up of a number of smaller bodies, which are made up of national governments grouped by planet
Is self-sufficient enough (because it's granularly made up of roughly self-sufficient worlds) to function day to day, so no empires that rely entirely on plunder or trade to keep cars working and people fed
Is settled in a tree-like pattern, with a strong main string of civilized systems which branch out into stellar frontiers

I think my setting prevents some inter-constate relations because an infinite universe reduces the need for conquest, their huge scale means there are no real constate-wide economies, and the self-sufficiency of their individual systems means there are no (or fewer) situations like in the real world where nation A is reliant on nation B's titanium production, or nation C invades nation D for their oil reserves. I can still see territorial and ideological wars being realistic, but the part that annoys me is that I don't see different constates interacting diplomatically in any interesting way besides defense treaties.
In-universe some highly hazardous planets have a technologically-interfering magical field which forms rare magic crystals which are used to produce infinite-use FTL engines and much more. Planets with similar but milder conditions also have unique plants, animals and minerals which are used to make tools for channeling magic into its various uses. The problem is that in a universe where a sufficiently powerful group of wizards could fling your moon into your planet's surface, I don't know if anyone would actually sell their limited magical resources to other entities.
I know the answer probably lies in making the groups within constates interact with each other, the equivalent of having California and the Mongolian People's Republic have diplomatic relations during the Cold War, but I wanted to see if there was some obvious answer I missed. My main question is whether it would it actually be feasible for an interstellar government to be made of planets which, collectively, require outside trade for some key resource? This would, in my eyes, fix the problem.

I think the answer to your question lies in the past
As I read your post it reminded me a lot about the economic and political conditions world-wide in the late 1700s during the Age of Sail. Travel between ports was slow, but manufacturing (not industrialization) was advanced. Technically there wasn't an organic resource that couldn't be grown locally if one was willing to put up with the trouble to do so. Nearly all resources existed to an extent in all locations. And yet trade flourished.
You have the same situation

One thing I think you're not considering is the scale of consumption. Have you read Asimov's Foundation series? Trantor had, what, twenty planets dedicated to agriculture just to feed its population? You could define your planets as intrinsically under populated (e.g., from the same Asimovian universe, the Spacer worlds that were completely balanced in their populations), and some would be, but assuming you're talking about humanesque people, they're breeding like rabbits. So you certainly do have a LOT of trade just in foodstuffs.

In a very similar vein is medical supplies, which depend on both manufacturing and raw resources. Humanity's recent experience with COVID-19 demonstrated part of the problem: getting the always limited resources of pharmaceutical manufacturing up to speed for a crisis. If you can't create what you need in a month's time, you ship it in from somewhere else. As large as your populated universe is, there could be regular need for this kind of service.

Looking momentarily at our own world today, just because everyone has the manufacturing ability and access to the raw resources doesn't mean everyone will have access to everything they need. The 2020-2023 global chip shortage underscored how it's really not universally true that every planet would be entirely self-sufficient. It's not that they aren't... it's that they aren't. Planet A builds a spectacularly good CPU and despite the fact that planets B through Z could build them if they wanted to, it's cheaper and easier to just buy them from planet A and use the resources that frees up for something else. History has kinda proven that as a world (Earth) becomes more technologically advanced and populated, the dependency on trade increases. The problem with the ubiquitous charge to "Buy American!"? It's cheaper to build it in China or Mexico. Your planets simply won't be carbon copies of one another.

And just like during the Age of Sail, where there's slow shipping... there be pirates! Nobody wants war, right? But they do want to stick it to their neighbor who just insulted someone's dog at exactly the wrong state dinner. Tell me that I'm wrong! Besides, why pay to build hundreds of millions of widgets when you can just, um... borrow them from your unsuspecting neighbor and write it off as piracy! (Gee... sorry to hear about that bud! Those awful pirates really are a pain in everybody's rear end!) And with every widget you don't have to pay for, your population becomes more affluent, happier, and (above all) loyal!


So, do a little research into global trade during the Age of Sail. I think it will solve all your problems.

I see some parallels but the communication times in the Age of Sail were the same as the travel times, instantaneous communication changes the picture a lot, especially when it comes to piracy, nothing makes it impossible if people are desperate enough though.

@Ash I don't know what you're expecting... there is no time in human history that exactly matches what the OP is looking for. The point of this Stack is to help people rationalize their worlds. The Age of Sail is a great starting point for the OP's needs because product delivery in a month trumps instantaneous communication. It might be nice to know the moment the pirate attack takes place... but it still takes two weeks to get a rescue ship out there. That's why I'm advocating looking at the nature of trade during that period.

Yes it takes time to get rescue there, probably too much time, but it also takes time to get a pirated vessel and/or cargo to a port of sale. In the age of sail they didn't know a ship was even overdue until the one behind it showed up, so pirates could fence their ill gotten gains with relative ease, in a world where a bulletin about the cargo being hot gets to port before the pirates it's a different situation, very much like Serenity, the episode not the movie where the crew get stuck with their "salvage" because their fence knows they got caught before they do.

@Ash :-) Privateers.

Always the safer way to pirate your way around if you can get a sponsor.

Under the current constraints you effectively have the modern world writ large across the stars. Instantaneous, or at least very fast, communication of needs across interplanetary and interstellar distances means you can arrange shipments and multi-port shipping routes in real time. Travel times on the scale of weeks means that orders can be filled on a time scale that allows shipping of even somewhat perishable goods like reasonably durable foods, grain or even apples.
Trade in bulk resources between star systems never makes a lot of sense, you have to work, hard, to create a situation in which large scale interstellar shipping beats in-system mining and statite-based space farming. Within the individual star systems having worlds (or population centres at least) being interdependent makes economic sense for the same reason that resource shipping does in the modern world; extraction is cheaper where the resources are plentiful, manufacturing where population is, and shipping product to wealthier markets increases profit margins.
Between star systems you might see shipping of rare elements such as Indium, Rhenium and, in particular, Phosphorus from systems where they are relatively common to areas where they're less available. You might also see systems that are particularly rich in industrial elements becoming manufacturing centres that can undersell other systems' local industry for large finished objects like starships, maybe. The main trade is going to be in IP though, mainly art, but also patents for new tools, machines, and toys.
In terms of inter-Constate interactions, they have no real reason for competition, and rarely, if at all, any grounds for trade though they'll possibly swap IP. There might be issues where there is a deep ideological divide between Constates that creates tensions/conflict. They're going to have to be really determined to do much about those conflicts on a physical rather than diplomatic level though. Even there meaningful sanctions are going to be hard to create and probably harder to enforce with large open frontiers.

Even in a realistically-scaled galaxy, some planets will be more desirable than others.

Even resources which are found on a lot of planets all across the galaxy: on a few planets they will be slightly more abundant or slightly easier to harvest than on others. Which gives those planets a sligth economical advantage. You wouldn't want to leave the best of the best planets to some other faction.
Some planets might be relevant for some scientific reason. Alien precursor artifacts, weird geography, unusual ecosystems or some extreme orbital properties. Those other factions might claim that they will be willingly share all the secrets they find, but would they really share everything?
Some planets will be of unique cultural significance for some historic reason. Can't have those heretics soil the birth-place of your prophet with their dirty refineries.
Location, location, location. Why harvest your resources tens of thousands of light-years away, when you can harvest them right at your doorstep? Oh, because those people claim that planet.
"We were here first": Two nations try to send settlers to the same planet at the same time and can't agree on who has the stronger claim to the planet. "We discovered it" - "But we surveyed it" - "But we were the first to land on it" - "Yes, a probe, but we landed the first human" - "Hey, that so-called probe had a sentient AI on board, so that should count. Anyway, we sent the first actual colonists who had the intention to stay" - "But our colonists were the first to build a permanent structure" - "You falsified those date records!" - "No, YOU falsfied YOUR date records!"...

Those conflicts could all escalate into aggression and then into all-out interstellar war. Unless you have diplomats who find peaceful compromises.

You have a serious problem
Unless all you worlds are included in and I quote 'In-universe some planets naturally produce rare magic crystals which are used to produce infinite-use FTL engines and much more'
Those worlds that do have access to the crystals in question? Will dominate all those worlds that don't. There may be (as you noted) worlds with rare resources that other worlds need but? The ones controlling interstellar trade have the final say over who gets what.
Think of it as being like the spice trade before Paul Atriedes comes along. Unless most if not all planets have access to the crystals required for interstellar travel and with Human nature being what it is? A cartel of worlds who do have access will inevitably form.  And once it does? It will dominate all the worlds that don't i.e. the cartel will dictate who gets what resources, when they get them and on what terms.

Sorry, I probably should have stated the conditions more clearly. The worlds which produce crystals are roughly distributed between constates, and their surface conditions are highly hazardous, also interfering with many technological systems. Do you think those worlds being disrupted by spontaneous explosions and needing to be replenished by outside citizens would change the outcome, or is lust for money just that strong?

@LordWungus as a general rule the answer to "how greedy can humans get?" is "yes".
